# ubuntu install OpenJDK 7 failed

Tags: ubuntu, installation, java

When I install OpenJDK I get a message on console:

```
seekting@seekting-2016:~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Package openjdk-7-jre is a virtual package provided by:

oracle-java9-installer 9b140+9b140arm-1~webupd8~3
oracle-java8-installer 8u111+8u111arm-1~webupd8~0
oracle-java7-installer 7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1

You should explicitly select one to install.
```

What can I do to successfully install the OpenJDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ma de, da bu liao zhongwen

I think it was you input has some error, copy the name from apt-cache search and post it on you command, don't use the Chinese input method, switch to English input method, you can add me in 2672406516 at qq, and...speak Chinese....

Comment: thanks ,I use your source.list, and run commond
apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk 
it works OK

Answer (score 0):

You can search the openjdk first like this

```
apt-cache search openjdk
```

then choose the correct jdk to install

Comment: seekting@seekting-2016:~$ apt -cache search openjdk

E: Opening configuration file ache - ifstream::ifstream (2: No such file or directory)

what's wrong?

Comment: @seekting zhang 都是中国人就别说英语了。。。你先update一下，然后再用apt-cache

Comment: apt-cache search openjdk

oracle-java7-installer - Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 7

oracle-java6-installer - Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 6

oracle-java8-installer - Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 8

oracle-java9-installer - Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 9


Hi, Jay Chouzz What can I do next?thanks

Comment: 我按您说的 然后出来一堆让我选的，不知道啥意思

Comment: 现在apt的仓库里已经移除openjdk-7的支持了，只有8和9了，你装8和9中的随便一个就行，握爪

Comment: 啊，那我要装opensdk7用来编andorid 系统源码的，其它版本好像不行，肿么办

Comment: seekting@seekting-2016:~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdkReading 

package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk

Answer (score 0):

I run the command

```
apt-cache search openjdk
```

and there are no openjdk-7 version, there just have openjdk-8, and openjdk-9, so, maybe you can install the openjdk-8 or openjdk-9 like this:

```
apt-get install openjdk-9-jre
```

or

```
apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

Comment: root@seekting-2016:~# apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-8-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openjdk-8-jre' has no installation candidate

Comment: 大神，为啥我装8就报错了呢，难道是源不对？